# Custom Number formatting?

Tags: qliksense

I have a Qlik Sense chart with one Dimension and one measure. the numbers I got from the measure is (99,999861) I need a custom format pattern to have the numbers like 99,99 %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click edit, choose the chart, open the data tab, expand the measure, under number formatting select custom. Format pattern would be something like this.

```
#,##0.00%
```

Comment: you Know I have tried this expression and many others and all have not worked. then I noticed that I have a small mistake in the measure expression (brackets order :|).

Thanks Chris J :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Introduction/conventions-number-time-formats.htm

A few specifics from that page:

> To denote a specific number of digits, use the symbol "0" for each digit.
>
> To denote a possible digit to the left of the decimal point, use the symbol "#".
>
> To mark the position of the thousands separator or the decimal separator, use the applicable thousands separator and the decimal separator.